# django - pre-set request.DATA in a variable that won't change

Tags: python, django

I have a view where I'm doing some modification on the request.DATA and then splitting into a few serializers but I still want to keep a master copy of the request.DATA.  Problem is the variable I set changes as the data changes.

```
    data_full = request.DATA
    print data_full
    print "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    event_details = request.DATA['event_action_details']
    schedule_details = request.DATA['event_schedule_details']
    request.DATA.pop('event_action_details')
    request.DATA.pop('event_schedule_details')
    print data_full
```

I want data_full to represent the initial state of the entire request.DATA.  I think want to break out the related serializer data but that last print data_full shows the more recent modifications with 'event_action_details' and 'event_schedule_details' removed.  I don't want this.

So how do I save the first example of request.DATA as a variable that is static and not to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Python doc about binding](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

In your case you are not making a independent copy of *request.DATA* in *data_full*, but you are only making another bind to the same dict.

To accomplish what you want to do try something like this:

```
 data_full = dict(request.DATA)
```

In this way you are building a **new**, independent dict with the same data. [This article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/) explains very well the concept and is worth a reading.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually just found the solution and this was it.  I actually ended up doing `data_full = request.DATA.copy()`